# Convergence related to Dominated convergence

Tags: real-analysis, probability, convergence-divergence

Let X : (Ω, F, P) → (R, B) satisfy E[|X|] < ∞. If $A_n ∈ F$ is a sequence of sets
with $lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} P(A_n) = 0$, then prove that $lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} E[|X|1_{A_n} ] = 0$.

Here is my thought using Dominated convergence theorem,

Since, $|X|I_{A_n} \leq |X|, E[|X|] < \infty $, then By DCT, we have $lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} E[|X|1_{A_n}] = E[lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}|X|1_{A_n}]$. The left thing need to show is $$lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}|X|1_{A_n}=0, a.s.$$
Can anyone help to derive a rigorous proof of the last line?

Btw, if E[|X|] < ∞ , is $X < \infty$ almost surely ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general,

$$|X| 1_{A_n} \to 0 \qquad \text{almost surely}$$

does **not** hold. Just consider the space $((0,1],\mathcal{B}(0,1])$ endowed with the Lebesgue measure, $X:=1$ and

$$\begin{align*} A_1 &:= \bigg( \frac{1}{2}, 1 \bigg] \\ A_2 &:= \bigg(0, \frac{1}{2} \bigg] \\ A_3 &:= \bigg( \frac{3}{4}, 1 \bigg] \\ A_4 &:= \bigg( \frac{1}{2}, \frac{3}{4} \bigg] \\ \vdots & \end{align*}$$

This means that your approach doesn't work.

---

**Hints:** Fix $\epsilon>0$. Obviously,

$$\mathbb{E}(|X| 1_{A_n}) \leq \int_{A_n \cap \{|X| \leq R\}} |X| \, d\mathbb{P} + \int_{A_n \cap \{|X| >R\}} |X| \, d\mathbb{P} =: I_1+I_2$$

for any $R>0$.

1. Using the monotone convergence, show that we can choose $R>0$ sufficiently large such that $$I_2 \leq \int_{|X|>R} |X| \, d\mathbb{P} < \epsilon.$$
2. Show that $$I_1 \leq R \mathbb{P}(A_n).$$
3. Conclude.

Comment: +1. Please excuse my error earlier, I misread the question.